# Error While Adding WebService Reference : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: discoveryError & mexError

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm, asmx

Steps I followed to add the service reference:

1. Add Service reference
2. Click Advanced
3. Click Add Web Reference
4. Add the url : https://suyatitechie.crm8.dynamics.com/AppWebServices/EmailSignatureService.asmx
5. Hit the  "**->**" button
   After this in the right panel I get the

   > Value cannot be null.
   >   Parameter name: discoveryError & mexError

Could not find any resources regarding this. anyone with the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Add the 'References' for dll System.Web.ApplicationServices
2 - Find the below tag in your web.config

```
    <system.web>
    ....
     <webServices>
       <protocols>
          <remove name="Documentation"/>
       </protocols>
     </webServices>
    </sytem.web>
```